# How to use AWS SAM CLI to execute a Step Function locally?

Tags: aws-step-functions, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to figure out how to set up a local development for AWS Step Functions and run the entire workflow without consuming the aws resources.

I have initialized a project using the "Step Functions Sample App (Stock Trader)" template, which has the following state machine graph:

[image]

At this point I have managed to test the execution by running just one lambda function at a time with `sam local invoke StockCheckerFunction`.

Is there any way to run the entire workflow at once locally?

stock_trader.asl.json

```
{
    "Comment": "A state machine that does mock stock trading.",
    "StartAt": "Check Stock Value",
    "States": {
        "Check Stock Value": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "${StockCheckerFunctionArn}",
            "Retry": [
                {
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                        "States.TaskFailed"
                    ],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 15,
                    "MaxAttempts": 5,
                    "BackoffRate": 1.5
                }
            ],
            "Next": "Buy or Sell?"
        },
        "Buy or Sell?": {
            "Type": "Choice",
            "Choices": [
                {
                    "Variable": "$.stock_price",
                    "NumericLessThanEquals": 50,
                    "Next": "Buy Stock"
                }
            ],
            "Default": "Sell Stock"
        },
        "Sell Stock": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "${StockSellerFunctionArn}",
            "Retry": [
                {
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                        "States.TaskFailed"
                    ],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                    "MaxAttempts": 3,
                    "BackoffRate": 1
                }
            ],
            "Next": "Record Transaction"
        },
        "Buy Stock": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "${StockBuyerFunctionArn}",
            "Retry": [
                {
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                        "States.TaskFailed"
                    ],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                    "MaxAttempts": 3,
                    "BackoffRate": 1
                }
            ],
            "Next": "Record Transaction"
        },
        "Record Transaction": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "${DDBPutItem}",
            "Parameters": {
                "TableName": "${DDBTable}",
                "Item": {
                    "Id": {
                        "S.$": "$.id"
                    },
                    "Type": {
                        "S.$": "$.type"
                    },
                    "Price": {
                        "N.$": "$.price"
                    },
                    "Quantity": {
                        "N.$": "$.qty"
                    },
                    "Timestamp": {
                        "S.$": "$.timestamp"
                    }
                }
            },
            "Retry": [
                {
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                        "States.TaskFailed"
                    ],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 20,
                    "MaxAttempts": 5,
                    "BackoffRate": 10
                }
            ],
            "End": true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both AWS Step Functions Local and AWS Lambda running on your local machine, then you can test your state machine and Lambda functions without deploying your code to AWS.

Follow these steps:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local-lambda.html

Comment: Thank you, I somehow missed that part of the documentation. Is there any way to use a state machine defined locally, or at least reference the code from a file, without having to provide the definition when running the `create-state-machine`? I have added the definition on my state machine in the description.

Comment: Just for information purposes (seeing that the question in the comment above is old).  You can use  ... create-state-machine --definition file://my-workflow.asl.json ...